# content of listview does not appear

Tags: android, listview, adapter

my code is running without error but the custom Listview does not display the values .

my code is running without error but the custom Listview does not display the values .

this is my code:

the Adapter

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
 ArrayList<mealItems> itemList;

public Activity context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;


public DiseasesAdapter(Activity context,int x,ArrayList<mealItems> itemList) {
    super();

    this.context = context;
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public Object getItem(int position) {

    return itemList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView img;
    TextView Title;

}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.disease_row, null);

        holder.Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    Items bean = (Items) itemList.get(position);
    holder.Title.setText(bean.getTitle());
    holder.img.setImageResource(bean.getImage());


    return convertView;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: from getCount() method, return itemList.size().

Answer (score 2):

Your `getCount()` method returns a 0, this should return the size of the `itemList` instead.

i.e `return itemList.size()`

Comment: hey, this is correct, your getcount is returning 0 and thats the reason why. do this: 

return ((itemList != null) ? itemList.size() : 0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
this.itemList=new ArrayList<mealItems>();
this.itemList.addAll(itemList);
```

And of course, the getCount() method to return itemList.size()